# R - NLP - Extract pair

Tags: r, nlp, udpipe

- Hi guys I'm new to the NLP algorithm with R.  I would like to extract a pair ( VERB-Noun) from a pdf? I'm stuck at a frequency of words topic. Like "Represent clients in criminal and civil litigation and other legal proceedings, draw up legal documents, or manage or advise clients on legal transactions. May specialize in a single area or may practice broadly in many areas of law."
- I would like to extract the verb-noun of these. Hou I would do?

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(udpipe)
> docs <- "Represent clients in criminal and civil litigation and other legal proceedings, draw up legal documents, or manage or advise clients on legal transactions. May specialize in a single area or may practice broadly in many areas of law."
> docs <- setNames(docs, "doc1")
> anno <- udpipe(docs, object = "english", udpipe_model_repo = "bnosac/udpipe.models.ud")
> anno <- cbind_dependencies(anno, type = "parent")
> subset(anno, upos_parent %in% c("NOUN", "VERB") & upos %in% c("NOUN", "VERB"), 
+        select = c("doc_id", "paragraph_id", "sentence_id", "token", "token_parent", "dep_rel", "upos", "upos_parent"))
   doc_id paragraph_id sentence_id        token token_parent dep_rel upos upos_parent
2    doc1            1           1      clients    Represent     obj NOUN        VERB
7    doc1            1           1   litigation    Represent     obl NOUN        VERB
11   doc1            1           1  proceedings   litigation    conj NOUN        NOUN
13   doc1            1           1         draw    Represent    conj VERB        VERB
16   doc1            1           1    documents         draw     obj NOUN        VERB
19   doc1            1           1       manage    documents    conj NOUN        NOUN
21   doc1            1           1       advise      clients    conj NOUN        NOUN
22   doc1            1           1      clients    Represent     obj NOUN        VERB
25   doc1            1           1 transactions      clients    nmod NOUN        NOUN
32   doc1            1           2         area   specialize     obl NOUN        VERB
35   doc1            1           2     practice   specialize    conj VERB        VERB
39   doc1            1           2        areas     practice     obl NOUN        VERB
41   doc1            1           2          law        areas    nmod NOUN        NOUN
```